# Dilation of specific points

Tags: matlab, mathematical-morphology

I would like to know if it is possible to make a dilatation only on certain points of a skeleton. For example if we take the image if below is it  possible to dilate only the points of the skeleton corresponding to the upper left and the left bottom point of the rectangle? (The coordinates of each point would be known)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use another array to apply dilation on:

```
% create example matrix
A = false(100);
A([2 end-1],[2:end-1]) = 1;
A([2:end-1],[2 end-1]) = 1;
A(sub2ind(size(A),2:99,2:99)) = 1;
A(sub2ind(size(A),99:-1:2,2:99)) = 1;
subplot(121);
imshow(A);
title('original');
% decide points for dilation
pointsForDilation = [2,2;9,9,;99,99];
hold on;
plot(pointsForDilation(:,1),pointsForDilation(:,2),'xr','MarkerSize',10,'LineWidth',2);
% create a matrix for dilation
B = false(size(A));
B(sub2ind(size(B),pointsForDilation(:,2),pointsForDilation(:,1))) = 1;
% dilate matrix B
C = imdilate(B,ones(5));
% add dilated matrix to original
res = A | C;
subplot(122);
imshow(res);
title('desired points dilated');
```

and you'll get this:
[image]